# How to get the fb and g+ email programmatically in ios?

Tags: facebook, google-plus, ios7.1

I have integrated fb and g+ login for my ios app. and If phone already sign in with the fb its automatically log in when click the fb button. But I want to send the email of the user in fb and g+ to the server separately. Can anybody tell me how can I get the email from fb and g+ both.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any user data (profile, birthday, email, etc.) without requesting specific permission from the user. It's a matter of following the SDK guide really.

You can request a user's information by making a me request. And you can do this in two ways:

Using the FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:completionHandler: method, like you did in the requesting permissions section, and setting the path to me.
Using the FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler: method, which will make a me request directly.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph

It's hard stuff that you will need to go through as a developer. Following how others did it by code will help you. But reading through the SDK guide will make you understand better.

Comment: you mean the email that user use to log to the fb right. Cant we get it from the phone directly?

Comment: It's up to you if you want to save the user data after getting their permission from fb locally  or in your database. Then you can use them at anytime.